# How to use the table columns instead of variables in QueryExpression::addCase()

Tags: mysql, cakephp, orm, case, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHPs new ORM, you can use the QueryBuilder to build (in theory) any query.

I want to select the value of one of two columns, depending on another value. In a regular query, that can be done as follows:

```
SELECT IF(from_id = 1, to_id, from_id) AS other_id FROM messages;
```

I am trying to archive the same query using the QueryBuilder and [QueryExpression::addCase()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Database.Expression.QueryExpression.html#_addCase)

```
$messagesQuery = $this->Messages->find('all');
$messagesQuery->select([
    'other_id' => $messagesQuery->newExpr()->addCase(
        $messagesQuery->newExpr()->add(['from_id' => $this->authUser->id]),
        ['to_id', 'from_id'],
        ['integer', 'integer']
    )
]);
```

This does not work, as the passed values are not integers, but rather table columns *containing* integers.

Through trial and error (using the method `add()` again), I got the following:

```
$messagesQuery = $this->Messages->find('all');
$messagesQuery->select([
    'other_id' => $messagesQuery->newExpr()->addCase(
        $messagesQuery->newExpr()->add(['from_id' => $this->authUser->id]),
        [
            $messagesQuery->newExpr()->add(['to_id']), 
            $messagesQuery->newExpr()->add(['from_id'])
        ],
        ['integer', 'integer']
    )
]);
```

This results in the following query:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN from_id = 1 THEN to_id END) AS `other_id` FROM messages Messages
```

Now, the `ELSE` part is missing, although the [CakePHP book states](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#case-statements):

> Any time there are fewer case conditions than values, addCase will automatically produce an if .. then .. else statement.

The [examples in the CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#case-statements) are not very helpful in this case, as they only use static integers or strings as values, for example:

```
#SELECT SUM(CASE published = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS number_published, SUM(CASE published = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS number_unpublished FROM articles GROUP BY published

$query = $articles->find();
$publishedCase = $query->newExpr()->addCase($query->newExpr()->add(['published' => 'Y']), 1, 'integer');
$notPublishedCase = $query->newExpr()->addCase($query->newExpr()->add(['published' => 'N']), 1, 'integer');

$query->select([
    'number_published' => $query->func()->sum($publishedCase),
    'number_unpublished' => $query->func()->sum($unpublishedCase)
])
->group('published');
```

## Is there a way to get the method `addCase` to use the two table columns as values instead of just static values?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, I was just one logical step short of the solution in my previous edit.

As the [CakePHP book correctly states](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#case-statements):

> Any time there are fewer case conditions than values, addCase will automatically produce an if .. then .. else statement.

For that to work though, **both the conditions and values have to be an array**, even if there is only one condition. (This the CakePHP book does not state.)

This code:

```
$messagesQuery = $this->Messages->find('all');
$messagesQuery->select([
    'other_id' => $messagesQuery->newExpr()->addCase(
        [
            $messagesQuery->newExpr()->add(['from_id' => $this->authUser->id])
        ],
        [
            $messagesQuery->newExpr()->add(['to_id']), 
            $messagesQuery->newExpr()->add(['from_id'])
        ],
        ['integer', 'integer']
    )
]);
```

results in this query:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN from_id = 1 THEN to_id ELSE from_id END) AS `other_id` FROM messages Messages
```

*Eureka*